# Is it permissible to have relationships to parents of parents for JSON:API resources?

Tags: json, api, design-patterns, json-api

I have the following hierarchy:

```
venue -> concert -> booking
```

And within booking I have a relationship for the concert. But should the booking also have a relationship to the venue? Or is it bad practice to have relationships at that depth?

What about if there was also a seat in a booking? Would a relationship to venue still be reasonable?

Or is it better to instead do two requests to get the venue? E.g. use the booking -> concert relationship to then get the relationship between the concert and venue?

Answer (score 1):

The relationships in your JSON:API response object should match the real world. I don't see any value of having a direct relationship between *booking* and *venue* if the relationship is through *concert* in reality.

You don't need a direct relationship to avoid additional request. JSON:API specification supports including deeply nested relationships.

Assuming the bookings are available from a `GET /bookings` endpoint, a client could ask the backend to include *venues* doing a `GET /bookings?include=concert.venue` request (assuming that the relationships is named `concert` on `booking` and `venue` on `concert`). The concert will be included implicitly.

Please find more information about sideloading related data in [Inclusion of Related Resources](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes) and [Compound Documents](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents) chapters in JSON:API specification.